# Save Base64 formatted data to excel

Tags: node.js, excel, xlsx

I have to create a new excel file from the base64 data. I'm getting base64 content from the s3 bucket and I have to save the excel file in the temp directory for further processing using node.js.

I tried converting the base64 to string using Buffer and then save to excel. Even though the file is created but it is corrupted.

I have used `xlsx` and `node-xlsx` npm module, but none is working.

Any lead will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code you used

Comment: Thanks, Musa, to remind me to share the code. The else statement was missing from my code. So, after creating an excel file using xlsx npm module, I was again creating the file using the default fs method. I'm writing my fix as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on a problem statement where I have to create a folder structure by reading the JSON file.

The xlsx npm module is working fine.  Here in my code `innerItem.fname` is filename and `innerItem.content` is excel content in base64 format.

```
        if (path.extname(innerItem.fname) === ".XLSX") {

          const bf = Buffer.from(innerItem.content);
          // console.log(bf.toString());
          // xlsx npm  const XLSX = require("xlsx");
          const workbook = XLSX.read(bf.toString());
          XLSX.writeFile(workbook, `${directory}/${innerItem.fname}`);
        } else {
          await fs.writeFile(`${directory}/${innerItem.fname}`, innerItem.content);
        }
```